# Dell Latitude - HDMI output is unreliable

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Dell Latitude E5540 laptop that cannot connect to two Samsung monitors using HDMI (both syncmasters, one is a P2450, the other is a S24C650PL).

Using VGA always works on both monitors, HDMI occasionally works on the syncmaster S24C650PL, but not the P2450. If HDMI does work, it can cause the mouse to stutter.

I have tried the following with no success:

- installing latest Nvidia drivers
- installing latest Intel GFX drivers from Dell website
- installing latest Intel GFX drivers from Intel website
- disabling auto input detect on the monitor (apparently Intel doesn't support this!)
- installing Samsung driver disk
- uninstalling Samsung driver disk
- forcing Nvidia GFX as "preferred"

Both screens are a standard 1920 x 1080 resolution.

Occasionally, plugging in the VGA using the display for a bit and then removing it and plugging in HDMI can bring the HDMI port to life.

Comment: I have to ask, are you using the same hdmi cable and are there any converters on any ends of the cable?

Comment: Different cables, no converters.

Comment: I've just tried the cable from my xbox just to check on a 3rd, also had the same problem.

Comment: Then you might possibly be dealing with a faulty/broken hdmi port on your laptop. Usually when it falls out after a certain amount of time, it's because of some sort of lose connection, if it's not the cable and not a converter, then the only option is unfortunately the ports.
Have your tried connecting your xbox to both screens, to make sure they run just fine?

Comment: I haven't recently, but I've used the HDMI input on the monitor before for xbox and my desktop fine. It's not that it stops working (like a loose cable) but it never establishes a connection to begin with, if it manages to, then it works fine

Comment: Well it really sounds like the hardware is somehow misbehaving and/or a buggy hdmi port, so sadly I think you will have to mark this one as unfixable, unless a repair guy takes a look at it.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case, but thought it would be worth checking to see if there were any known issues with the drivers or dell/samsung compatibility

Comment: I don't know if there might be, but you seem to have tried installing most of the different drivers, without luck, so my money would be on the hardware. :/